# OneDrive SDK & background task WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive, background-task

I'm trying to use the [OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UniversalOneDriveSdkSample) in a background task (Windows Runtime Component) but I get an error when I try to authenticate:

```
var result = await Authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(new[] { serviceTicketRequest }, CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded)
```

Error I get: `The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)`

I have posted this query on the [MSDN forum here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf8975c5-6934-4406-8f8b-2acb018f7469/wp81wp81-store-app-universal-background-task-and-onedrive-sdk-error-at-auth?forum=wpdevelop).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I had to record the access token and use it afterwards for next calls. But it is granted only for 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xamarin by any chance? In that case the crasch is the result of a bug when trying to debug a 64 bit process.

Comment: no, just using the windows universal app templates. with compilation set to any cpu.